# Filtering out non-English words from a corpus using `textcat`

Tags: r

[Similar to this SO member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078604/detect-text-language-in-r), I've been looking for a simple package in R that filters out words that are non-English.  For example, I might have a list of words that looks like this:

```
Flexivel
eficaz
gut-wrenching
satisfatorio
apropiado
Benutzerfreundlich
interessante
genial
cool
marketing
clients
internet
```

My end goal is to simply filter out the non-English words from the corpus so that my list is simply:

```
gut-wrenching
cool
marketing
clients
internet
```

I've read in the data as a `data.frame`, although it will subsequently be transformed into a corpus and then a TermDocumentMatrix in order to create a wordcloud using `wordcloud` and `tm`.

I am currently using the package `textcat` to filter by language. [The documentation is a bit above my head](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v52/i06/paper), but seems to indicate that you can run the command `textcat` on lists.  For example, if the data above was in a data.frame called `df` with a single column called "words", I'd run the command:

```
library(textcat)
textcat(c(df$word))
```

However, this has the effect of reading the entire list of words as a single document, rather than looking at each row and determining it's language. Please help!

Comment: I voted to close because this question is asking for a package recommendation.  Maybe tweak the question to how you would do this in R and show you did some leg work.  Also eliminate the bonus question.

Comment: Define "English words."  (Hint: you can't.)

Comment: @TylerRinker - Thanks for the input. I found the `cldr` package that uses Chrome to detect languages, but that seems to apply a probabilistic judgment to generate a guess about the "top three possible languages". This is a bit more sophisticated than what I need, so I was looking for a simpler dictionary based approach. I'll keep scouting, and make the question more specific once I find an option. (PS, I love `qdap` :))

Comment: @roody the problem is textcat (as Carl alludes to) is going to tell you origins so only gut wrenching is an English word.  One approach may be to use a dictionary of English words (maybe like qdap's `DICTIONARY[, 1]` data set).  Then stem this and the list of words and use `%in%` or a `lookup` environment to determine the words that are "English"

Answer (score 0):

For a dictionary search you could use `aspell`:

```
txt <- c("Flexivel", "eficaz", "gut-wrenching", "satisfatorio", "apropiado",
  "Benutzerfreundlich", "interessante", "genial", "cool", "marketing",
  "clients", "internet")

fn <- tempfile()
writeLines(txt, fn)
result <- aspell(fn)
```

`results$Original` gives the non-matching words. From those you can select the matching words:

```
> result$Original
[1] "Flexivel"           "eficaz"             "satisfatorio"      
[4] "apropiado"          "interessante"       "Benutzerfreundlich"
> english <- txt[!(txt %in% result$Original)]
> english
[1] "gut-wrenching" "genial"        "cool"          "marketing"    
[5] "clients"       "internet"
```

However, as Carl Witthoft indicates you can not be sure that these are actually English words. 'cool', 'marketing' and 'internet' are also valid Dutch words for example.