# Text preprocessing in a different language

Tags: r, quanteda

With this options it is possible to make a preprocessing text analyis for english language

```
dflemma <- 
  spacy_parse(structure(df2$term, names = df2$id), lemma = TRUE, pos = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(id = sub("(.+)-(.+)", "\\1", doc_id)) %>% 
  summarise(text = paste(lemma, collapse = " "))

myCorpus <- corpus(dflemma[["text"]], docnames = dflemma[["id"]])

mystopwords <- c("can")
myDfm <- myCorpus %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)  %>%
  tokens_remove(pattern = c(stopwords(source = "smart"), mystopwords))  %>%
  dfm(verbose = FALSE)
```

How is it possible to make for german and greek language the removal of stopwords and stemming?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. That includes a sample of data and the packages you're using. Also, it's not the same question, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8078604/5325862) has some resources that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both German and Greek are found in the stemming and stopword language lists, so both should be easy to apply in **quanteda**.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.2.0.9000
## Unicode version: 13.0
## ICU version: 69.1
## Parallel computing: 8 of 8 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

txt_german <- "Wie kann ich eine natürliche Sprachverarbeitung für Texte in anderen Sprachen durchführen?"
txt_greek <- "Πώς μπορώ να πραγματοποιήσω επεξεργασία φυσικής γλώσσας σε κείμενα σε άλλες γλώσσες;"

tokens(txt_german, remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(stopwords("de")) %>%
  tokens_wordstem(language = "de")
## Tokens consisting of 1 document.
## text1 :
## [1] "natur"           "Sprachverarbeit" "Text"            "Sprach"         
## [5] "durchfuhr"

tokens(txt_greek, remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(stopwords("de")) %>%
  tokens_wordstem(language = "de")
## Tokens consisting of 1 document.
## text1 :
##  [1] "Πώς"            "μπορώ"          "να"             "πραγματοποιήσω"
##  [5] "επεξεργασία"    "φυσικής"        "γλώσσας"        "σε"            
##  [9] "κείμενα"        "σε"             "άλλες"          "γλώσσες"
```