# Use R or Python to detect multiple languages in one column of a csv-file

Tags: python, r, multilingual, text-recognition

I have a csv-file with one variable "comment" where the content can be in different languages. I now would like to create a new variable "language" that tells me which language is written in the mentioned variable "comment".
Any idea on how to create this new language variable and make the language detection work?

Comment: This post may help :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142778/how-to-determine-the-language-of-a-piece-of-text/74834385#74834385

Comment: You might want to check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078604/detect-text-language-in-r